# Toilet too close to wall

Tags: plumbing, walls, toilet

I have a toilet that is too close to the sidewall. It is a slab foundation. What are my options for fixing this without ripping up the floor?

I thought orginally an offset toilet flange but I need more than two inches. Would a corner toilet work in this scenario?
[image]

UPDATE:
Here is another picture
[image]

Comment: Have you checked to see if there's enough room to rotate it 90 degrees, move the cabinet?

Comment: Could you move the wall?

Comment: It is an exterior wall so I can't move it. That cabinet is a sink and the door is just swung open.

Comment: sit with 90 degree in which part has space.

Comment: Can you sketch a floorplan or take a different photo showing the sink? I'm wondering if anything can be done with the sink.

Comment: If you spun the toilet 90 degrees, would it fit? You could probably install a wall-hung sink on the right-hand wall.

Comment: Need to pull the toilet to get real measurements to see what the options are. Then you find a toilet, or a reconfiguration, that fits those options, or you bust the floor up.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, Since the pipe exits at the back, after the trap, I dont see how turning it around is going to do anything. Wont it be too close to the other wall?

Answer (score 1):

Use a sledge hammer and break up enough concrete to do the plumbing and ask hardware store for the right stuff to do the plumbing. Pounding a hole in the concrete is not a big deal i know it sounds scary but once the plumbing is where you need it your problem is solved. The repair will be hidden under the floor tile or whatever finished floor your going with anyway. Be sure you know the measurements of where the new flange should be and a plan for required to do the job by asking at the hardware store. If you still are uncertain then don’t do it. Plan on a couple of days for it to dry and your clean up. If you have all of your material ahead of time it will go much quicker.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use a wall mounted toilet and snake the drain from the base of the wall drain to the floor drain.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Given that the floor is a concrete slab, how would this work?

Answer (score -2):

its really not that hard to break up the concrete and move the toilet over.  the whole move can be done easily in a day with very little mess.  then you just have to replace/repair the flooring and install the toilet.

Comment: While true, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: ... and it's hard to break up the concrete and move the toilet over...

Comment: okay.  here's a better direct answer to the question.  you have no options without ripping up the floor other than building up a false floor.  since that's a solution that will mean more time and labour, then the answer is no.  an offset flange will not work, and a corner toilet won't work (with the caveat that you can butcher together any possible number of ways of doing it, but none of them are a good solution that will work and preserve resale value of the home)

Comment: to address the comment about concrete breaking and moving of the toilet, that's simply untrue.  we do about 10 of these a year, and its only about 6 hours work for 2 guys with another 2 hours for a competent plumber to re-plumb the closet in the middle of the work.  a days work and you are just left with flooring and the toilet install.  if that's your definition of hard work, you definitely wont be working for me anytime soon.  you might want to try something easier, like cabinetry.

Comment: Ha ha... I think when you say that something can be done "easily in a day" on a DIY site without specifying the number of people involved, you're apt to confuse things. I see from your comment that you've actually specified 14 hours of work by experienced professionals, who presumably have the right equipment... And, just wondering, did those 14 hours include pouring new slab after the plumber is gone? Did your time include hauling waste? Was removing the cabinet (which looks like it sits on the finish floor) in or out?

Comment: I thought this was a home improvement site.  doesn't specify that its DIY.  I can tell by some of the answers that there are many very competent pros on here.  I myself have made a career for the last 25 years of improving homes, as did my father and his father before him.  since you seem like you must do something else to earn your money, heres how it would go:

Comment: fan in window to remove dust - 1 minute.  remove toilet -15 minutes.  plastic over walls and vanity - 15min.   slit saw (wet) the floor with assistant vacuuming slurry as you go - 1 hour.  break out floor area to expose closet and plumbing - 1 hour.  (waste removed by assistant as you go - 100lbs, 1 garbage can)  vacuum out aggregate to expose pipes - 30 min.  plumber gets in and does his thing - 2 hrs.  level excavation with new aggregate - 5 min.  compact - 5 min.  mix and pour new concrete (usually 6-10 bags) - 1 hour. lots of time for lunches, breaks or thinking of ways it can't be done.

Comment: forgot to clarify, this is for non-union workers who are highly skilled, competent at problem solving, and motivated to get the work finished.  if unionized, it will need 4 more guys, one steward, one engineer, one supervisor and three more days

Comment: In fact. despite the annoyingly misleading URI, this area is not limited to do-it-yourselfers. However many of the participants are trying to put in as much sweat equity as they reasonably can, so it's good practice to indicate whether a time estimate is for DIY, for one experienced worker, or gor a team. If you don't make that ckear, we'll ask... (grin)

Comment: Despite being downvoted, from personal experience   this is the best solution. I  see another similar answer isnt downvoted.